# How to find which sandbox a user was created in?

Tags: sandbox, login, help

A *friend* asked me how to figure out which sandbox their user was created in because the username is not being allowed to be reused.

Attempts to use Forgot Your Password? at test.salesforce.com have not triggered any emails nor are there any historical emails from the original invitation. We've got 50 orgs with ~25 sandboxes each, so a manual search is...unappealing.

And Salesforce Support only taunts us by confirming that the username does exist but won't reveal which org.

Any clever ideas? Or at least amusing sympathetic anecdotes?

Comment: By any chance, have you connected(authorize) your orgs with VS code? @Always Thinkin

Comment: I have but this enduser definitely would not have used anything other than the UI.